# Type 'Category' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Tags: swift

I'm tying to bring 2 property values from another view controller with a protocol func to append an object (Book) to the value of a Dictionary in an array of Dictionaries [Categories] that I've instanciated in the main one.

The Category object has a constructor with dictionary: a key name:String, and a value:[Books]

When I'm trying to do this with the protocol function, the bug appears when I'm doing the dictionary for "Type 'Category' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'"

I really have no idea what to do.
I'm so new with this, PLEASE HELP!
Thanks!

```
// protocol to add new book
    protocol AddBookDelegate {
        func addNewBook(name: String, book: Book)
    }

// mainViewController + categories array + protocol func

class BooksTableViewController: UITableViewController, StockQuantityDelegate, AddBookDelegate{

    // categories array
    var todasLasCategorias: [Category] = []

    // protocol func to add a book
    func addNewBook(name: String, book: Book) {
            for eachCategory in todasLasCategorias{
                for (myKey, myValue) in eachCategory{
                    if myKey == name{
                        myValue.append(book)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

//Category declaration
class Category {
    private var name: String
    var books: [Book]?

    init(name:String){
        self.name = name
    }

    init(with dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? "no name"
        self.books = []
        if let apendeoLibros = dictionary["books"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
            for objectSelected in apendeoLibros{
                let newBook = Book(with: objectSelected)
                books?.append(newBook)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: eachCategory It is not a sequence. You need to show it’s declaration if you would like further help

Comment: Where can I find the declaration? I'm really new, sorry

Comment: I meant `Category` declaration

Comment: so you want to iterate your `books` property?

Comment: eachCategory it is a Category object, not a dictionary (key, value) pairs collection

Comment: I pretend to bring a new book from the other view to this one, and append it to [books] in the correct category, by first search the name category that comes from the new book, compare with de name of each category instead in the array of categories and once that I found it, append the new book to the books array of that category.... I don't know if I'm explaining myself ok, let me know please

Comment: `eachCategory.name`